# JSON array conversion into multi dimension array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

I am new to Javascript and trying to convert data that I am getting from mongodb into multi dimension array like example below. If this could have been simple conversion of values in straight array than this could have been done using for loop but not sure how multi dimension array conversion can be done?

Please help.

```
[
    {
        "text": "p",
        "count": 26
    },
    {
        "text": "ne",
        "count": 5
    },
    {
        "text": "n",
        "count": 69
    }
]
```

Need multi dimension array like below:

`[["p",26],["ne",5],["n",69]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the array through [`Array.protoype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which replaces each value in the array with whatever the callback function returns. In the callback function you can return an array version of the object.

For example:

```
var result = yourArray.map(function (item) {
    return [item.text, item.count];
});
```

More array methods can be found on the [MDN docs for Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).