# JSON nested "nth level" objects array conversion into multi dimension array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

With reference to [JSON array conversion into multi dimension array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588889/json-array-conversion-into-multi-dimension-array). I want to convert `nested object` into multidimension array.

```
[{
  "name": "level1",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "level2",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "level3",
      "val": 1,
      "subCategory": null
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "level1",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "level2",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "level3",
      "val": 2,
      "subCategory": null
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "text": "level1",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "level2",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "level3",
      "val": 3,
      "subCategory": null
    }]
  }]
}]
```

into

```
[
  ["level1", "level2", "level3", 1]["level1", "level2", "level3", 2],
  ["level1", "level2", "level3", 3]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
var data = [{ "name": "level1", "subCategory": [{ "name": "level2", "subCategory": [{ "name": "level3", "val": 1, "subCategory": null }] }] }, { "name": "level1", "subCategory": [{ "name": "level2", "subCategory": [{ "name": "level3", "val": 2, "subCategory": null }] }] }, { "text": "level1", "subCategory": [{ "name": "level2", "subCategory": [{ "name": "level3", "val": 3, "subCategory": null }] }] }],
    result = [];

function iterator(array, names) {
    names = names || [];
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var n = names.concat(a.name);
        if (Array.isArray(a.subCategory)) {
            iterator(a.subCategory, n);
        } else {
            result.push(n.concat(a.val));
        }
    });
}

iterator(data);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: what about `nth-level` not just three??

Comment: @ozil, now it goes for every level.

Comment: `[
        null,
        "level2",
        "level3",
        3
    ]` there should be `level1` instead of `null`

Comment: no, because the property has the name `text` and not `name`.

Comment: can new structure be converted back to previous structure?

Comment: @ozil, no,because the properties like `val` are missing.

Comment: @ Nina Scholz I want  `[["level1","level2","level3",1],["level1","level2","level3",2],[null,"level2","level3",3]]` back to `[{"name":"level1","subCategory":[{"name":"level2","subCategory":[{"name":"level3","val":1,"subCategory":null}]}]},{"name":"level1","subCategory":[{"name":"level2","subCategory":[{"name":"level3","val":2,"subCategory":null}]}]},{"text":"level1","subCategory":[{"name":"level2","subCategory":[{"name":"level3","val":3,"subCategory":null}]}]}]` structure

Comment: you still have the problem with the `null` value in the 3rd array. where should it map to?

Comment: no, it is working fine, I want to convert this `mutli dimension array` back to `nested object` as it was original.

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/f5bvokbo/)

```
var sampleData = [{
  "name": "level1",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "level2",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "level3",
      "val": 1,
      "subCategory": null
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "level1",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "level2",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "level3",
      "val": 2,
      "subCategory": null
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "text": "level1",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "level2",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "level3",
      "val": 3,
      "subCategory": null
    }]
  }]
}];

function transform( data )
{
  var output = [];
  for ( var counter = 0; counter < data.length; counter++ )
  {
    var obj = data[ counter ];
    var level1 = obj.text;
    var level2 = obj.subCategory[ 0 ];
    var level3 = obj.subCategory[ 0 ].subCategory[ 0 ];
    output.push( [ obj.text, level2.name, level3.name, level3.val ] );
  }
  return output;
}

console.log( transform( sampleData ) );
```

Comment: there could be `n` level, sample is for three levels

Comment: @ozil your original question didn't mentioned that part. Either update the question or raise a new question.

Comment: question title says nested objects

Comment: @ozil It didn't says nested till n-levels. Anyways share the code that you have tried.